# Proving Continuity in a Partial Differential Equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Let
$v(x,t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{Q(s,t)u(x,s)ds}$, where $Q(s,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}e^{\frac{-s^2}{4t}}$.

Suppose that $D=\left\{(x,t):x\in (-\infty,\infty), |t|\le 1\right\}$, and that $v(x,t)$ is a solution to a diffusion equation $v_t=v_{xx}$.

How can I show that if both $u_{tt},u_{xx}$ are continuous on $D$ and that $u_{tt}-u{xx}=0$ only outside of $D$, then there must exist some $\xi\in(-1,1)$ s.t. $u_{tt}(x,\xi)-u_{xx}(x,\xi)=0, \forall x\in(-\infty,\infty)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $Q(s,t)$ is a heat kernel, satisfying the heat equation:
$$Q_t=\frac{1}{4t\sqrt{\pi t}}e^-{s^2}{4t}\left(1-\frac{s^2}{2t}\right)=Q_{ss}$$

Now, from this that:
$$v_t(x,t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\partial_tQ(s,t)u(x,s)\,ds=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}Q_{ss}(s,t)u(x,s)\,ds=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}Q(s,t)u_{ss}(x,s)\,ds$$

$$v_{xx}(x,t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}Q(s,t)u_{xx}(x,s)\,ds$$

Since $v_t-v_{xx}=0$ and from $u_{xx}(x,s)-u_{ss}(x,s)=0$ for $\left|s\right|\le 1$, we get that:
$$0=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}Q(s,t)(u_{xx}(x,s)-u_{ss}(x,s))\,ds=\int_{-1}^{1}Q(s,t)(u_{xx}(x,s)-u_{ss}(x,s))\,ds=(u_{xx}(x,\xi)-u_{ss}(x,\xi)\int_{-1}^{1}Q(s,t)\,ds$$

Now, do you see how this shows your result?